# Positioning of a figure at the bottom of a page

Tags: floats, positioning

I am using the package `\usepackage{graphix}` to add a figure. I want the figure to go at the bottom of the page so I am writing the code like this:

```
\begin{figure}[b]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{Figures/graphs/a-CACC.eps}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
```

The figure goes to the end of the document instead of the bottom but if I use [H], it gets at the same page as the code. I do not see the problem here.

Comment: `[b]` by default has to be at most 30% of `\textheight`. As you do not allow `t` or `p` going to the end of the document is the most likely outcome. try `[!bp]`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you that helped. If I needed a figure and a table both at the bottom of the page. What notations would I use?

Comment: same for both. If you need lots of these, change `\bottomfraction` to allow more float space, but for one-off use `!` means "ignore `\bottomfraction` so allows over size floats, and almost always you should include `p` so a floatcan be placed on a float page and not forced to the end of a document

Answer (score 2):

`[b]` by default has to be at most 30% of `\textheight`  (`\bottomfraction` is `0.3`). As you do not allow `t` or `p` going to the end of the document is the most likely outcome. Try `[!bp]`.

If you need lots of these, change `\bottomfraction` to allow more float space, but for one-off use `!` means "ignore `\bottomfraction`" so allows over size floats. Almost always you should include `p` so a float can be placed on a float page and not forced to the end of a document